# Uploading File to S3, then process in EMR and last transfer to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I am new in this forum and technology and looking for your advice. I am working on POC and below are my requirement. Could you please guide me the way to achieve the result.

1. Copy data from NAS to S3.
2. Use S3 as a source in EMR Job with target to S3/Redshift.

Any link, pdf will also helpful.

Thanks,
Pardeep

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot here that you're asking and there's not a lot of info on your use case to go by so I'm going to be very general in my answer and hopefully it at least points you in the right direction.

1. You can use Lambda to copy data from your NAS to S3. Assuming your NAS is on-premise and assuming you have a VPN into your VPC or even Direct Connect configured, then you can use a VPC enabled Lambda function to read from the NAS on-premise and write to S3.

If your NAS is running on EC2 the above will remain the same except there's no need for VPN or Direct Connect.

2. Are you looking to kick off the EMR job from Lambda? You can use S3 as a source for EMR to then output to S3 either from within Lambda or via other means as well.

If you can provide more info on your use case we could probably give you a better quality answer.

Comment: Thanks @alanwill, below are the other details.

1. Yes my first use case to pull data from on premise NAS and then from shared third party open location using credentials.
2. We have use Lambda as well, please let us know if there is any other alternative to kick EMR job. Is there any way to write data directly to Redshit through EMR (Spark SQL). Or we need to copy result to S3 then load to Redshift through Lambda.

Comment: Yes you can write data directly to Redshift from EMR, here's the doc link on how http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-from-emr.html. You can also automate the entire pipeline in Lambda to create and execute the job, if you're using Python you can use the boto3 SDK https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html

Answer (score 1):

> Copy data from NAS to S3.

Really depends on the amount of data and the frequency on which you run the copy  job. If the data in GBs, then you can install AWS CLI on a machine where NFS is attached. AWS CLI command like CP can be multithreaded and can easily copy your datasets to S3. You might also enable S3 transfer acceleration to speed things up. Having AWS Direct connect to your company network can also speed up any transfers from on-premis to AWS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html

https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/

If the data is in TBs (which is probably distributed across multiple volumes), then you might have to consider using physical transfer utilities like AWS Snowball,AWSImportExport or AWS Snowmobile  based on the use-case.

https://aws.amazon.com/cloud-data-migration/

> Use S3 as a source in EMR Job with target to S3/Redshift.

Again, as there are lot of applications on EMR, there are lot of choices. Redshift supports COPY/UNLOAD commands to S3 which any application can make use of.   If you want to use SPARK on EMR , then installing  databricks **spark-redshift**  driver is a viable option for you.

https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/10/19/introducing-redshift-data-source-for-spark.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/powering-amazon-redshift-analytics-with-apache-spark-and-amazon-machine-learning/